# Cloud function on update get content of both parent and child node

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with firestorm cloud functions, I've designed my database as such that we have chatRooms and each chat room has a sub-collection called messages, I want the function to be triggered when a new message is sent so I've done this

```
exports.notifications = functions.firestore.document('MyChats/{chat_room_id}/message').onWrite((snapShot,context)=>{

});
```

so every time a new document is written to the messages sub collection this function will be triggered, I need to get some information that is stored inside the chatRoom document, I've created a field that has a value that tells me if the other person is inside the chat room or not, if they are inside the chat room then I will not send notification to them, how can I access the information stored inside the chat room document when the function is triggered without having to download the document myself, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the example data model (beware not to show anything sensitive), and which fields you want to read ?

Comment: I found a way to solve my problem, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem, I didn't want to put the trigger on the chat room because the function will be triggered every time the user leaves the chat room.
when the user leaves the chat room the value that indicates that he is inside the chat room will change to false, in result the chat room will be updated and the function will be triggered, the function will check if the user is inside that chat room or not (he isn't) and then a notification will be sent to him, altho no new messages were sent.

how did I solve this problem? if we use the snapshot.before and snapshot.after we can solve this problem, let's explain, when we are inside the chat room the indicator value is true when I leave the chat room the value will be updated to false, so we check before value of the snapshot, in this case, the function will check the before value of indicator (which is true) and it won't send a notification (the user is inside the chatroom no need to send notification).

but what if the user is outside the chat room and he enters the chat room? in this case, the value of the indicator is false and will be changed to true,  the function will check the before value of the indicator (which is false) and send a wrong notification, so what do we do? the solution is that both the before and after value of the indicator has to be false, let me explain why.

let's explain this in 4 scenarios.

1- the user is outside the chat room when he receives a message, so when the chat room updates the before and after value of the indicator is false(only the information that indicates that a new message is received will be updated), the notification will be sent correctly.

2- the user is inside the chat room when he receives a message, the before and after value of the indicator is true(the user is inside the room don't send notification), so no message will be sent.

3- the user is inside the chat room and he leaves, so the before value is true and the after value is false, the notification will not be sent.

4- the user is outside the chat room and he goes inside the room, the before value is false and the after value is true, no notification will be sent.

I hope this helps anyone who's having the same problem as me, have a good time!